# How to configure package2 features?

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm trying to create a Package2 vesion and I getting the following error

```
Unable to parse package2-descriptor.json: invalid value for field 'features' at line 1, column 756
```

My package depends on several features. 
I tried below configurations withoud success. The error is the same.

1. **Array**

   "features": [ "MultiCurrency", "PersonAccounts", "ServiceCloud", "Communities", "CustomerSelfService", "CustomApps",  "DefaultWorkflowUser", "LightningServiceConsole", "LightningSalesConsole", "CustomApps"]
2. **Comma separated values**

   "features": "MultiCurrency, PersonAccounts, ServiceCloud, Communities, CustomerSelfService, CustomApps, DefaultWorkflowUser, LightningServiceConsole, LightningSalesConsole, CustomApps"

Any Idea? The doc [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev2gp_config_file.htm) dos not explain the format of the value of this configuration in case of multiple values.